# Is there any equivalent function in C++ as the astype() function in python?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, python-3.x, type-conversion

I am looking for a function that can cast every element of an array to float type in c++ (like what astype() do in python).
Do you know any?

Thanks

Comment: There is none. Primitive types are not polymorphic.

Comment: `std::static_cast<float>(whatever)`.

Comment: I need a function that cast every element of the array to float.

Comment: @mzar Well something like `float[] float_arr = cast_to_floats(int_arr);` won't work because you can't assign to an array.

Comment: @mzar any reason why you do not want to copy array of integers to array of floats?

Comment: Thank you all. Actually I filled my array with floats and I need it to be float but I got an error that indicating there may not be floats in my array. Some one with same problem (in python) and same error solve it with astype() function. Thats why I was looking for an equivalent.

Comment: Can you post the actual code and the error message?

Comment: In C++, an array of floats can only contain floats. So your problem isn't very clear. Perhaps if you posted an MCVE...

Comment: @Galik you can find the code in the other question that I asked and I would be so appreciate if you could help me with that. (Because it's not relevant to this topic I couldn't ass it here. Sorry..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast individual items to `float`, but you can't cast an entire array at once.

You can pretty easily create a vector of `float`s that contains the values from your original array, with each individually cast to type `float`:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
std::vector<float> asFloat(T (&input)[N]) {
    return std::vector<float> {input, input+N};
}
```

Note, however, that this creates a new array of `float` values created from those in the original array, without changing/affecting the original array at all. Also note that since this is a template, it's possible to apply it to any type for which a conversion from T to `float` is defined, even if that conversion might not make a whole lot of sense or produce particularly useful results (e.g., `char`):

```
char input[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

auto result = asFloat(input);
```

If you print out the contents of `result`, you'll typically get:

```
97      98      99
```

That's the encoding of `a`, `b` and `c` in most common character sets (ASCII, Unicode, etc.) but those don't really make a whole lot of sense as floating point values.

Based on comments, however, you're just trying to create an array of `float`. There are a couple of minor details to deal with here. One is that you probably really want a `vector` instead of an array. Another is that floating point literals are of type `double` by default. Initializing a `float` variable with a `double` value can (and frequently will) lead to a warning about possibly losing data, or something similar.

So, when you're initializing an array or vector of `float`, you usually want to include a suffix to force the values to type `float`:

```
std::vector<float> values { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```